# JS как в цикле загрузить неизвестное колличество изображений

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, client

Для галлереи нужно загрузить все доступные изображения с папки. Число их неизвестно, и при этом все должны быть загружены.

В приведенном ниже коде проблема, скорее всего, в том, что нужно переписать асинхронно, что бы добавлять и остановить при ошибке.

```
const бетоны = [];
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
    //бетоны.push(image.src);
}
var sw = 1;
image.onerror = function () {
    sw = 0;
    console.log("Cannot load image");
}
for (var i=1;i<5;i++) {
    image.src = "../images/бетон-"+ i +".jpg";
    if (sw === 0) return;
    бетоны.push(image.src);
    console.log(image.src);
}
console.log(бетоны);
```

Есть ли более эффективный способ это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### как проверить существование файла а затем загрузить его с помощью JavaScript

это набросок идеи, а не проверенный рабочий код. настоятельно рекомендую разобраться и переписать под себя

```js
let foo = url => fetch(url, { method: 'HEAD' })
    .then(r => {
        if (r.ok) {
            console.log(`HEAD: запрашиваемый url <${url}> существует`)
            return fetch(url, { method: 'GET' })
        }
    })
    .catch(console.log.bind(console, 'Error:'))

foo('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')
    .then(r => {
        if (r.ok) {
            console.log(`GET: запрашиваемый url <${r.url}> is OK`)
            return r.text()
        }
        else throw new Error('что-то не так при загрузке')
    })
    .then(text => {
        console.log(`text.length ${text.length}`)
    })
    .catch(console.log.bind(console, 'Error:'))
```

---

[MDN HTTP/Заголовки/If-Modified-Since](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/If-Modified-Since)

https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch

https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#promise-all-iterable

Comment: Спасибо! работает. только вот пишет Error: TypeError: "r is undefined"
<anonymous> ... в if (r.ok) { ---- если дать не ссылку на несуществующий файл, вместо обработки ошибки.

Comment: 1) это набросок идеи, а не проверенный рабочий код. настоятельно рекомендую разобраться и переписать под себя 2) `if (r&&r.ok)`

Comment: 3) `Error: TypeError` это как раз. скорее всего сработал `catch` попробуйте написать свою функцию обработки ошибок и заменить ей `console.log.bind(console, 'Error:')`